# How to add predefined colors to <input type="color">?

Tags: html, color-picker, preset

According to MDN, the `list` attribute can be used for `<input>` elements of type `color` to provide a list of predefined colors. That page also [indicates that `list` is supported at least in Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#Browser_compatibility).

Though when I specified some colors they were not shown as expected using Chrome 67. Instead, only empty items were shown in the color picker popup and clicking on them set the value of the input to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

[image: Predefined colors for <input type="color"> not shown in Chrome]

Simple example:

```html
<input type="color" list="presetColors">
<datalist id="presetColors">
  <option value="#ff0000"/>
  <option value="#00ff00"/>
  <option value="#0000ff"/>
</datalist>
```

I tried to specify the colors in different formats like used in CSS, e.g. `rgb()` or color keywords like `red`, though none of them worked.

Having a look at the HTML specification, it says that the input only [accepts "lowercase simple colors"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#color-state-(type=color)), which is defined as the 6-character hex format.

So, is that a bug in Chrome or am I supposed to specify the colors in a different format?

Comment: For me, on firefox this just opens the standard colorpicker.

Comment: That's because Firefox currently (as of Firefox 60) doesn't support the `list` attribute. This is requested in [bug 960984](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=960984).

Comment: If I modify the options one by one to use a different format via dev tools, then the gray squares disappear one by one, and once all option values are changed, Chrome displays the “default“ color picker again … So based on that I’d say the _format_ is probably correct, and implementation still buggy.

Comment: @CBroe That's also my impression, especially as the specification dictates the hex format, though I was still wondering if Chrome accepts another format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this format for list:

```
 <input type="color" list="presetColors">
  <datalist id="presetColors">
    <option>#ff0000</option>
    <option>#00ff00</option>
    <option>#0000ff</option>
  </datalist>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/4045/

**Note:** As mentioned, this works only in chrome now.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't think of putting the value into the tag content, as other elements work with the 'value' attribute. But I also just found out that [this bug is already fixed in Chrome 68](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849130).

Comment: it doesn't work on chrome beta now

Comment: For me this works on Firefox and Chrome rn, it just behaves different (in chrome it is a dropdown with only the provided option until you hit `other`, in firefox it directly goes to a color picker but with the options stored in custom presets)

Answer (score 2):

For color type, the options datalist suggests the recommended color on the swatch palette. Must be in hexadecimal format

Please check this, hope this will help you :)

```html
 <h3>input[type="color""] with &lt;datalist></h3>
            <p>For <code>color</code> type, the options  <code>datalist</code> suggests the recommended color on the swatch palette. Must be in hexadecimal format</p>
            <input type="color" id="color" value="#ee0000" list="reds" />
            
            <datalist id="reds">
              <option>#ff0000</option>
              <option>#cc0000</option>
              <option>#990000</option>
              <option>#660000</option>
              <option>#330000</option>
              <option>red</option> <!--ignored as invalid -->
              <option>#F00</option> <!--ignored as invalid -->
            </datalist>
<h3>Quirks</h3>
<p>Notice the different look of the color picker when no <code>list</code> attribute is included:</p>
<input type="color" id="color2" value="#ee0000" /> - no list attribute
<br/>
<input type="color" id="color3" value="#ee0000" list /> -presence of list attribute, but no list
```

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: That works, though it's missing an explanation *why* it works. The reason was obviously that I put the values into the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tags, while they were expected to be set in the tag content. I just realized that [this bug already got fixed in Chrome 68](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849130).